# Equation in a fraction - have I solved it right?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm solving entrance maths example problems from a university. I solved this one:

> $\frac {2x-3}5 - \frac {4x+5}3=8$

My solution was `-104/14`  but in the answer sheet it's -11. Am I wrong? If so why?

Edit: I did the following steps:

1. $3(2x-3)-5(4x+5)=8$
2. $6x-9-20x+25=120$
3. $-14x=104$
4. $x= -104/14$

Comment: Please show your working so that we can help you

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. If we are to have any chance of answering why, you have to show us your work.

Comment: @Henrik I showed now

Comment: Note that you can simply plug your answer versus the given one into the equation to check if your answer is right.

Comment: @1524 I was just thinking about that)

Comment: The $8$ on the right in step $1$ should be $120$.  You fix that in the next line, so no lasting harm.

Comment: You can easily *debug* such equational proofs using the [methods described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+debug). In your case since you know the solution you can plug in $\,x = -11$ to find the first equation that is false, which will reveal your first error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot parentheses around the numerator of the second fraction.

The calculations should look like:
$$
\frac {2x-3}5 - \frac {4x+5}3=8\\
6x-9-(20x+25)=120\\
6x-9-20x-25=120\\
-14x-34=120\\
-14x=154\\
x=-11
$$

Answer (score 5):

Look at $$3(2x-3)-5(4x+5)=120 \iff 6x - 9 - 20 x \color{blue}{- 25} = 120$$

$-5(4x+5) = -20 x-25$; you added +25 instead of subtracting 25.

Comment: oh I got it, I thought they made mistake not me)

Comment: It happens; everyone of us makes such errors on occasion!  Thanks for the edit with the added work, btw!

Comment: yeah, I just lack practice. Thanks for you, not me))